# TestCafe debug footer blocks page interaction

Tags: debugging, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, ui-testing

I have buttons on the bottom of the screen that is covered up by the TestCafe footer when I stop for client-side debugging (t.debug).  When I select "Unlock Page" I can interact with my app except for any widgets under the footer.  My app has a button toolbar at the bottom which makes the manual interactive mode pretty useless.

*NOTE: I can tab to the buttons in the toolbar and hit enter, but this is not a workaround my QA department finds acceptable from an efficiency standpoint.*

Is there any way to make the footer disappear or to make the web page act as if its viewport ends above the footer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there's no way to hide the footer or move the page content above it. We are aware of this limitation and will work on improving this behavior in the context of this thread:

[Allow access to elements under the status panel in debug mode](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4136)

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Should I add an enhancement issue on Github or does that exist already?

Comment: You are welcome. You can track the issue I provided in my answer.